# Google maps autocomplete и маркеры на карте

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api, javascript

Работает автокомплит, но хочу еще чтобы при выборе адреса (например город Санкт-Петербург) карта переносилась на Питер и ставился маркер на карту.

И так и не понял как переинициализировать карту после того как она пришла аяксом на страницу.

Скрипт вызова карты:

```
var myMap;
var search_result = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    function initialize_map() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.7427928, 37.6154009),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapaddres'), mapOptions);
    }

    function autocomplete_map(div_id, div_id_result) {
      var input = document.getElementById(div_id);
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', myMap);
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
          lon = place.geometry.location.lng();
          $(div_id_result).val(lat + ',' + lon);
          console.log(lat + ',' + lon);
        });
    }
    initialize_map()
    autocomplete_map('user_city', '#user_city_coords');
  });
```

вот инпуты

```
<div id="mapaddres"></div>
<input class="input-xlarge focused" id="user_city" style="width:90%;" name="user[city]" required="" type="text">                                              <input id="user_city_coords" name="user[coords]" required="" type="hidden" value="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В событии, где вы получаете координаты от `autocomplete.getPlace();` попробуйте сделать так:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
myMap.panTo(myLatLng); // можно использовать setCenter(), но панТу красиво "проедется" к нужной точке
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: myMap,
  title:"Hello Piter!"
});
```

Comment: спасибо, а как можно переинициализировать функцию после того как карта пришла аяксом?

Comment: не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду... карта создается один раз - при старте скрипта, ссылка на нее прячется в глобальную переменную myMap. аяксом приходят данные в ответ на функцию изменения автокомплет. из этих данных можно взять координаты, чтобы с из помощью посадить маркер. Если нужно, чтобы маркер динамически перемещался соответственно изменению координат - то карту перегружать не нужно, нужно снять маркер с карты marker.setMap(null); изменить ему координаты (marker.setPosition(LatLng); и вновь повесить на карту: marker.setMap(myMap);